Windows 11 "Cast to Device" performs in very poor quality
I have a 65" TCL Android TV and I'd like to cast videos and pictures from my PC to the TV. The TV and the PC both connected to a fast router by cable. My PC identifies the TV and list it in the "Cast to Device" list (from the right click menu) but the result on the TV is very-very poor picture quality and huge lag while playing a video. It's not about color calibration or such, as suggested in another topic but the overall resolution, transmit speed and everything else just bad and completely unenjoyable. I tried to cast from Chrome browser it does the same crap quality and hugely lagged TC screen. I also tried from VLC and it's only turns black the monitor and nothing happens on the TV.
Here's a video about the problem. You may not see the low resolution part of the problem because the whole video uploaded at low res but the whole screen with the background displays as it stay in 1920x1080p and not upscaled to the 65" TV. But even if I try to cast a 6000x4000 image (recorded with my Nikon DSLR) it displays on the same low res.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/aLUsAHLQQy11f8Fw8
I don't have external devices like Chromecast or whatever, I believe in 2024 smart televisions with Android/whatever well used systems and gigafast internet connections should have display high-res images and movies on their own. So I hope this is just some settings in Windows or maybe I need a different program on PC to play them well. Any idea what should I do?

try casting to a different TV

What is the resolution of the content? What is the resolution of your computer's monitor that you are casting from? Casting is usually pretty poor quality and laggy, in my experience, regardless your devices.

the content quality could be even 6000x4000 pixel photo or 2160p movie, no matter, they're cast very low quality on TV. My monitor's resolution is 1920x1080. If "Cast to Device" performs poor quality generally then how do I play 4k content from PC to TV?
